# Problema em Query Builder Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, query

Estou em dúvida em uma query com joins em meu projeto, ao rodar o Select direto no banco não tenho problemas, porém quando a construo com Query Builder não obtenho resultados. Onde estaria errando na montagem dela?

**Query normal:**

```
SELECT EmpresaCNAE.*, empresa.*, ServicoValor.* FROM EmpresaCNAE 
INNER JOIN empresa on empresa.EmpresaId=EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId
INNER JOIN ServicoValor on ServicoValor.ServicoId=EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId
WHERE EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId=4721103 and ServicoValor.EmpresaId=EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId
```

**Query Montada:**

```
$Dados = DB::table('EmpresaCNAE')
        ->join('empresa', 'empresa.EmpresaId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId')
        ->join('ServicoValor', 'ServicoValor.ServicoId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId')
        ->where([['EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId', $id->id],['ServicoValor.EmpresaId', 'EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId']])
        ->select('EmpresaCnae.*', 'empresa.*', 'ServicoValor.*')
        ->get();
```

*$id->id contém o 4721103, fiz todos testes com o mesmo id*

Executando com toSql() recebo o seguinte:

```
select `EmpresaCnae`.*, `empresa`.*, `ServicoValor`.* from `EmpresaCNAE` inner join `empresa` on `empresa`.`EmpresaId` = `EmpresaCNAE`.`EmpresaId` inner join `ServicoValor` on `ServicoValor`.`ServicoId` = `EmpresaCNAE`.`CNAEId` where (`EmpresaCNAE`.`CNAEId` = ? and `ServicoValor`.`EmpresaId` = ?)
```

Testei outra forma de query porém sem resultados também:

```
$Dados = DB::table('EmpresaCNAE')->select('EmpresaCnae.*', 'empresa.*', 'ServicoValor.*')
->where('EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId', '=', $id->id)->join('empresa', function($join){
$join->on('empresa.EmpresaId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId');
})->join('ServicoValor', function($join){
$join->on('ServicoValor.ServicoId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId');
})->where('ServicoValor.EmpresaId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId')->toSql();
```

Resultado do toSql dessa ultima forma:

```
select `EmpresaCnae`.*, `empresa`.*, `ServicoValor`.* from `EmpresaCNAE` inner join `empresa` on `empresa`.`EmpresaId` = `EmpresaCNAE`.`EmpresaId` inner join `ServicoValor` on `ServicoValor`.`ServicoId` = `EmpresaCNAE`.`CNAEId` where `EmpresaCNAE`.`CNAEId` = ? and `ServicoValor`.`EmpresaId` = ?
```

Comment: depois do select() coloque assim `select('EmpresaCnae.*', 'empresa.*', 'ServicoValor.*')->toSql()` vai ter o retorno da SQL verifique se bateu com a normal?

Comment: Utilize o método `toSql()` para retornar a query que o Laravel está montando. Assim dá para comparar melhor.

Comment: Editei a pergunta @ValdeirPsr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando da seguinte forma:

```
 $Dados = DB::select('SELECT EmpresaCNAE.*, empresa.*, ServicoValor.* FROM EmpresaCNAE 
       INNER JOIN empresa on empresa.EmpresaId=EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId
       INNER JOIN ServicoValor on ServicoValor.ServicoId=EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId
       WHERE EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId = ? and ServicoValor.EmpresaId = EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId', [$id->id]);
```

E uma forma alternativa que também funcionou:

```
 $Dados = DB::table('EmpresaCNAE')
        ->join('empresa', 'empresa.EmpresaId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId')
        ->join('ServicoValor', 'ServicoValor.ServicoId', '=', 'EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId')
        ->where([['EmpresaCNAE.CNAEId', $id->id]])
        ->whereColumn([['ServicoValor.EmpresaId', 'EmpresaCNAE.EmpresaId']])
        ->select('EmpresaCNAE.*', 'empresa.*', 'ServicoValor.*')
        ->get();
```